# iMacros Script Form Filing not working with Event or Content Method

Tags: imacros

I am trying to fill up a form for the URL https://kite.zerodha.com
I tried filling up the form using xpath and event method, however both seems not to be working.

```
  TAG XPATH="//input[@type='text']" CONTENT=ABCDEF
```

The other known method is Event using keypress, however that also seems not be working

```
  EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS XPATH="//input[@type='text'] CHAR="ABCDEF"
```

I also tried to tried to use button click to highlight the cell, however nothing happens. Was wondering that is there any other way to make it work.

```
  EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN XPATH="//input[@type='text']" BUTTON=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you recorded the macro in **Experimental event recording mode**, you would get something like this:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#container>DIV>DIV>DIV>FORM>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>INPUT" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#container>DIV>DIV>DIV>FORM>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>INPUT" CHARS="ABCDEF"
```